# Reliably detect new visitors to a website

Tags: javascript, cookies, ip

I'd like to setup an introductory message to show to all new users. It should somehow store their info (cookie? IP address?) so that they (ideally) never see the message a second time. I know it's possible with cookies, but what is the most reliable way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't over think it. Just use cookies. If a user deletes their cookies regularly, chances are they understand the consequences of seeing such popups repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this reliably you would need to use Server Side Scripting. Javascript can be disabled and as such would not prove reliable anymore.

PHP would be simple - you can read the users IP address and User Agent (UA) with

```
<?php
    $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $UA = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
?>
```

Store that information into a database and you can track the user. Combine that with a cookie (however again, this could be deleted by the user) and you have a pretty good tracking solution.

```
<?php
   // Set a cookie
   $userID = 'something';
   setcookie('UID', $userID);

   // Read a cookie
   echo($_COOKIE['uid']);
?>
```

Have a look on http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php for info on cookies.

Comment: I would say cookies (using LocalStorage when available if you like) would be more reliable than this, because there are many situations where a users IP address will change regularly (even every request which happens with some proxies), OR there may be 1000 users behind one IP address. Cookies are for each computer (browser actually), and while they can be disabled, it would be trivial to check for disabled cookies and not show the popup if so.

Comment: This is true. I guess it does come down to personal preference. I store sessions in a database with a key that the user stores in a cookie. The database locks that key to only work with the IP of the user who initiated the session, unless the user specifies it to be a persistent login. That seems to get around the issue of changing IPs (very real issue with mobile devices)

Comment: Another thing - local storage is not always available to the users browser. Security policies and legacy browsers may pose an issue here.

Comment: True, but if it _is_ available it's better than a cookie as it doesn't waste bandwidth every request. Regardless of cookies vs localStorage, what you use depends on how you implement the popup; if the server is deciding to send it or not then localStorage isn't a option, however if the popup is handled client-side, then it's an option. (ie `if(localStorage){ [use localStorage] } else { [COOKIE TIME!] }`

Comment: Good point, I think the best option is a combination of the technology available. No single implementation will guarantee you are tracking the same user. However a mix of a few options is the best best.

Comment: "_To do this reliably_" using the IP address is not and cannot be reliable